# Selective reaction of a terminal alkene from a mixture of terminal and internal alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry

Isomerisation reaction of a internal alkene results in a mixture of internal and terminal alkene. I want to hydroxylate the terminal alkene alone. Rather than separating it from the mixture, is there any way to directly get the desired yield

Comment: So you want to separate or not? (Compare title with the rest...) There are selective catalysts and afair they prefer terminal alkenes, but I'm not sure if for this reaction too.

Comment: I mean, you could separate the mixture by vacuum distillation with precise temperature control and long Vigreaux columns.

Answer (score 3):

The reagent you want is disiamyl borane, which is selective for terminal alkenes over internal alkenes as shown by this [Organic Syntheses procedure](http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV7P0258) then work up with basic hydrogen peroxide to give primary alcohol.